# STDEV.P - ignore cells with value 0

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to calculate standart deviation, but I need a way to ignore the cells with value 0.

For example, in the following image, standart deviation of `J4:M4` should be `3.766` (ignoring `M4`). Since the location of the zeros are not fixed (not in the same column) I can't just use `J4:L4`. For the 6th row, I need to ignore `K6`.

I need a flexible solution, like `=AVERAGEIF(J4:M4,">0")`. How should I proceed?

[image]

Comment: Are columns J:M user entered values or are they formulas?

Comment: @Steven They are also formulas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to use this array formula:

```
=STDEV.P(IF(J4:M4>0,J4:M4))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the formulas in the input cells as such:

`=if( OriginalFormula <= 0, "", OriginalFormula )`

The `STDEV` (and several other)functions ignore any non-numeric value.

Comment: This is a much better solution if the formulas can be changed.